# CRC midstream instead of at the end

Tags: crc

Normally one would add a CRC to the end of the data stream.  The CRC check would include the CRC itself and return 0 if the CRC is correct.

I need to add a CRC to verify my embedded code.  It needs to be checked in place, but the top word in memory space is for an interrupt vector.  Is it possible to place a key value midstream such that the CRC check returns 0 for the whole code?  (or is this unsolvable?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's definitely possible. You can run a CRC backwards, which would be fast and easy. Below is example code.

In fact, you can give me the locations of bits scattered wherever in the stream, and if you give me enough of them I can tell you what to set them to to get a zero CRC at the end, or any other CRC value for that matter. My [spoof code](https://github.com/madler/spoof) solves the linear equations to come up with that answer.

However I would wonder why you'd want to do any of that. Why not just know where the CRC is stored and compute the CRC for everything but that, and then check the result against the stored CRC?

```
// Example of the generation of a "middle" CRC, which is inserted somewhere in
// the middle of a sequence, where the CRC is generated such that the CRC of
// the complete sequence will be zero. This particular CRC has no pre or post
// processing.
//
// Placed into the public domain by Mark Adler, 11 May 2016.

#include <stddef.h>         // for size_t
#include <stdint.h>         // for uint32_t and uint64_t

#define POLY 0xedb88320     // CRC polynomial

// Byte-wise CRC tables for forward and reverse calculations.
uint32_t crc_forward_table[256];
uint32_t crc_reverse_table[256];

// Fill in CRC tables using bit-wise calculations.
void crc32_make_tables(void) {
    for (uint32_t n = 0; n < 256; n++) {
        uint32_t crc = n;
        for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++)
            crc = crc & 1 ? (crc >> 1) ^ POLY : crc >> 1;
        crc_forward_table[n] = crc;
        crc_reverse_table[crc >> 24] = (crc << 8) ^ n;
    }
}

// Return the forward CRC of buf[0..len-1], starting with crc at the front.
uint32_t crc32(uint32_t crc, unsigned char *buf, size_t len) {
    for (size_t n = 0; n < len; n++)
        crc = (crc >> 8) ^ crc_forward_table[(crc ^ buf[n]) & 0xff];
    return crc;
}

// Return the reverse CRC of buf[0..len-1], starting with crc at the end.
uint32_t crc32_reverse(uint32_t crc, unsigned char *buf, size_t len) {
    while (len)
        crc = (crc << 8) ^ crc_reverse_table[crc >> 24] ^ buf[--len];
    return crc;
}

// Put a 32-bit value into a byte buffer in little-endian order.
void put4(uint32_t word, unsigned char *pos) {
    pos[0] = word;
    pos[1] = word >> 8;
    pos[2] = word >> 16;
    pos[3] = word >> 24;
}

#include <stdlib.h>         // for random() and srandomdev()

// Fill dat[0..len-1] with uniformly random byte values. All of the bits from
// each random() call are used, except for possibly a few leftover at the end.
void ranfill(unsigned char *dat, size_t len) {
    uint64_t ran = 1;
    while (len) {
        if (ran < 0x100)
            ran = (ran << 31) + random();
        *dat++ = ran;
        ran >>= 8;
        len--;
    }
}

#include <stdio.h>          // for printf()

#define LEN 1024            // length of the message without the CRC

// Demonstrate the generation of a middle-CRC, using the forward and reverse
// CRC computations. Verify that the CRC of the resulting sequence is zero.
int main(void) {
    crc32_make_tables();
    srandomdev();
    unsigned char dat[LEN+4];
    ranfill(dat, LEN/2);
    put4(0, dat + LEN/2);       // put zeros where the CRC will go
    ranfill(dat + LEN/2 + 4, (LEN+1)/2);
    put4(crc32(0, dat, LEN/2) ^ crc32_reverse(0, dat + LEN/2, (LEN+1)/2 + 4),
         dat + LEN/2);          // replace the zeros with the CRC
    printf("%08x\n", crc32(0, dat, LEN+4));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I was just hoping to avoid doing custom sequencing of the data through the CRC.

Comment: "know where the CRC is stored"  A difficulty with that comes from linking and restrictions on the software layout.  One can place a `uint32_t crc` as global data and it will appear somewhere in the image, but the exact location isn't known until the software is linked.  It may be difficult to place it at a predefined address.  E.g., it must go into the data section, which must immediately follow the code section, which is of a variable size.  Or a natural location like the start of the image must be used by an interrupt vector table.